# Como modificar un arreglo

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estoy resolviendo este problema:

Escribe un programa que lea una secuencia de  enteros y un entero  y que reimprima la secuencia dada, reemplazando los enteros que no son múltiplos de  por una X mayúscula.

Ya tengo la parte donde en arreglo reconoce cuales son los multiplos, pero me falta colocar las X en la parte del arreglo donde no hay multiplo.

```
int main(){
    
    int a,b;
    int res=0;
    
    cin>>a;
    
    int arr[a];
    char brr[a] = {'X'};
    
    for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    
    cin>>b;
    
    for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
        if(arr[i]%b == 0){
            cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
        }
    }
    
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que asi tiene que quedar el ejercico, ya solo me falta poner las X, pero no logro hacer eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Te hace falta escribir la acción en caso de que no sea múltiplo

En tu `if` ya consideras si es un múltiplo o no, solo agrega el `else`

```
if(arr[i]%b == 0){
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}
    else {
    cout<<brr[0]<<" ";
}
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    int res=0;
    
    cin>>a;
    
    int arr[a];
    char brr[a] = {'X'};
    
    for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    
    cin>>b;
    
    for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
        if(arr[i]%b == 0){
            cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
        }
        else {
            cout<<brr[0]<<" ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Solo una pregunta. Por que en el arreglo de brr[0], en vez de poner la i dentro de los corchetes, colocaste un 0.

Comment: Cuando inicializas un arreglo en C++, si el valor es diferente a `0` debes inicializar cada índice del arreglo, de lo contrario los valores no inicializados serán `0`, cuando haces esto en tu código `char brr[a] = {'X'};` suponiendo que `a` es `3` lo que sucede es esto `brr[0] = 'X'` `brr[1] = 0` `brr[2] = 0`. Además, al sustituir cualquier número por la misma letra `X` en realidad no necesitas un arreglo del mismo tamaño que `arr`

Answer (score 0):

Que tal amigo es bastante simple te comparto mi solucion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int a,b;
    int res=0;
    cout<<"Ingrese la cantidad de numeros a verificar:"<<endl;
    cin>>a;

    char arr[a];

    for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese el numero "<<(i+1)<<":"<<endl;
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    cout<<"Ingrese el numero el cual se verificara si son multiplos:"<<endl;
    cin>>b;

    for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
        if((int)arr[i]%b != 0){
            arr[i]='X';
        }
    }
    cout<<"Resultado:"<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

lo que realice fue:

```
char arr[a];
```

convertir primero el arreglo a uno de char para poder escribir las X, si deseas que admita números y no solo dígitos puedes colocar :

```
char arr[a][cantidad de dígitos que contendrá el numero];
```

posteriormente realice una modificación a tu comprobación:

```
    for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
        if((int)arr[i]%b != 0){
            arr[i]='X';
        }
    }
```

haciendo que primero convierta a entero el char y luego compruebe los que no son múltiplos de dicho numero, si no lo son cambia el valor que contiene esa posición por una X.
luego simplemente mostré todo el array :)
Espero te sirva :D